# what does 또한 mean here?

Tags: vocabulary

윤해솔과 함께 곡을 전반적으로 잘 끌고 가면서 자신의 역량 또한 숨김없이 드러냄.

[link](http://mlbpark.donga.com/mp/b.php?p=1&b=bullpen&id=201807170020558900&select=&query=&user=&site=&reply=&source=&sig=h4a9GY2Y6h9RKfX@hlj9Sl-g5mlq)

Comment: ――――― “As well.”

Answer (score 2):

윤해솔과 함께 곡을 전반적으로 잘 끌고 가면서 자신의 역량 또한
숨김없이 드러냈다.

In cooperation with 윤해솔, with singing(or dragging) a song well as a whole, he
exposed his ability without shrinking, too.

That is, he showed two : dragging and singing ability. Here 또한 is a coordinate conjunction. In general, 잘 끌고 가면서, 또한 자신의 역량을 드러 냈다 may be possible if we follow the mean of coordinate

[reference](https://dic.daum.net/word/view.do?wordid=kkw000075670&supid=kku000096328)

[Add] 그녀는 똑똑하고 또한 지혜롭다. She is smart and wise.

Like this case, under the symmetry, 또한 is placed in the middle.

공무원은 안정적인 직업이만, 스트레스 또한 많다. Government man is stable job, but it has a lot of stress.

In this sentence, there is a symmetry in meaning but none in structure. So 또한 is placed in back of emphsized noun.

Comment: So is this word order acceptable or do most people ddohun in the front??

Comment: In case of your example, placing in back is acceptable.